# Is there a way to test if a keyboard extension has been installed in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm creating a custom keyboard extension in iOS 8 using Swift, and I was hoping to be able to modify the home screen of the app based on whether the user has already installed the keyboard onto their device.

Is there any way to test if this has been done?

Comment: Hi, Any updates on this?